# Why are subsequent recurring contributions not recorded?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

It seems that only the 1st contribution in a recurring series is recorded in CiviCRM, and the others have to be noticed and entered manually. Is there any way that someone has found to fix this problem?

Comment: Which payment processor is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set an IPN.  [Instructions are here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/PayPal+Website+Payments+Standard+and+Recurring+Contributions).  Basically, PayPal needs to send a payment notification (an IPN) to CiviCRM every time they process a payment, so that Civi knows to update the record.  You need to tell PayPal what URL to send those IPNs to.  In my experience, PayPal does NOT automatically find the IPN address - so find the exact path to `civicrm/extern/ipn.php` in your path and supply THAT to PayPal for IPN.  Also note that PayPal changes their interface all the time, so the place in the PayPal control panel where you enter the IPN URL might have moved.

Comment: Thanks! I think that worked! We haven't had a recurring donation come in yet (and I'd have to wait a month if I set one up myself), but I did a test donation and it showed up as "completed" in CiviCRM. Thanks so much!

Comment: In case anyone else is running into this problem, I wanted to share that the instructions that helped us solve this issue (PayPal not finding the proper IPN address) is at [this wiki documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/PayPal+Website+Payments+Pro+and+Express+Configuration#PayPalWebsitePaymentsProandExpressConfiguration-RecurringContributions) which shows good example addresses for Drupal, Joomla, and WordPress.  For example, my solution, on Drupal, turned out to be: https://www.mysite.org/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific cron job for recurring contributions, which is filling in pending contributions as time progress.

Comment: I don't think this is true - which scheduled job are you thinking of?  Recurring contributions are generally set via IPN - which I think flywtink might not have set correctly, based on this and their other question.

Comment: @JonG I am thinking about "Process Offline Recurring Contributions".  Maybe I am wrong, but that is how I thought it was connected on my site at least.

Comment: pretty sure that's not core, but part of the Offline Recurring Payment Extension: https://civicrm.org/blogs/andyw/offline-recurring-payment-extension

Comment: @JonG, What is IPN and how do I set it up correctly so that recurring donations are recorded?
To clarify, the recurring donations *are* showing up in Paypal, they're just not being recorded automatically in CiviCRM.